# How do I get items of a field of type list?

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I have created a list field with 10 items(allowed values). Now I want to get that 10 items programmatically. How do I get them?

Answer (score 0):

Better create a vocabulary of taxonomy terms populated with your items.Then you can use taxonomy_get_tree() function to retrieve all those items

Comment: I can't change the field. There are many submitted nodes having this field.

Comment: The data is on the field_config table. Identify the row  by checking the value given for that select list from field_config.field_name column and use sql like this "select field_config.data from field_config WHERE id =field_config.id value". The allowed values will be the array ['settings']['allowed_values']

Comment: There's a working function implemented [here](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/return-drupal-cck-integer-field-allowed-values-list-array) that does the same thing